# How to obtain values from list

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

[image]

Hi Guys

Can anyone help me out with this problem i have a list of object that is formatted in the image attached above and i have to get the IDNO, Affected Id and the date values

Comment: Please post the full code for this, there's a couple of issues by the looks.

Comment: @JoeBrailsford am serializing the data on the javascript size and passing them to code behind using ajax calls after receiving the data am deserializing the data which is the formatted image

Answer (score 0):

Since deserialization will return `anonymous` type(in your case), you have two options: Either deserialize it to a strong type (by defining a type) or else fetch the value using **Reflection** since types and properties are not known.

In your case you can get the value through reflection like this:-

```
Dim _data As List(Of Object) = ...
Dim firstObject = _data.FirstOrDefault()
Dim type As Type = firstObject.GetType()
Dim idmoValue = type.GetProperty("IDMO").GetValue(firstObject)
```

[Sample Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xy5ImK)